# Existence of a map $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^* \mapsto \mathbb{F} $

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Is there a map between the group of $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$ where $N$ is a composite number , a product of two equal size secure prime numbers $p$ and $q$ and a finite field $\mathbb{F}$, such that for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$ there is a polynomial representation of $x \in \mathbb{F}$ ?

Comment: Based on chinese remainder theorem there is an isomorphism: $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^* \mapsto \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}^* \times \mathbb{Z}_{q^2}^*$ And if $p$ and $q$ are primes then $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{q^2}^*$ constitute a field. I think this is one possible solution

Comment: What do you mean by "a polynomial representation of $x$"? Would a constant polynomial suffice? Do you want that map to preserve some structure? Another thing that worries me is that neither $\Bbb{Z}_{p^2}$ nor $\Bbb{Z}_{q^2}^*$ is a field.